# How can I avoid External Error, Security Error, in Python coding?

Tags: python

First of all, I have no idea what this error means. I've tried avoiding it by defining (the_red),(the_blue),(the_green) by defining them as global values, but it still doesn't work. Can anyone help me, please?

[image]

Comment: Please avoid using screenshots to show your code and error messages - you should paste the formatted code directly into your question.

Comment: What environment is this? `CanvasRenderingContext2D` is generally a web thing, i.e. JavaScript and so on, but you have Python code here.

Comment: I don't know actually...I'm a grade ten student studying online in a competition called Nashia Scheme. They said we're coding python, but didn't specify anything else. Could you enlighten me?